# Repo based Android app not updated through Phonegap API, however, "Update code" button on site works

Tags: phonegap-build

**Problem:**
Issuing a PUT request to "api/v1/apps/:id" with a payload of "{"pull":"true"}" says it was successful, however, when I check the APK it is using the previous build.  It is NOT pulling the latest from github.  I can load and run the APK, it is just not the latest code.

When I login to the Adobe PhoneGap Build site and click the "Update code" button it DOES pull the latest from github and builds the app.  The APK also loads and runs fine.

**Questions:**

- Do I need to bump a version flag somewhere in order for the API to pull latest?  If so, what file(s) and what flags do I need to update?
- Is there an API call or payload that I can send that will trigger a pull from github?
- Is the update api call supposed to pull the latest from github?

**Notes:**

- I am using Phonegap version 6.3.4
- I followed the steps outlined on the PhoneGap Build Docs
- I am using the "cli project format"
- Currently only targeting Android
- I am pulling from master branch on github, not from a tag
- I have "version="0.0.1"" and "android-versionCode="10"" as attributes in the the widget element of my config.xml

Thank you for any help you can provide.

I also posted this question on the [Phonegap Build forum](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9105875#9105875) feel free to answer it in either location.

Comment: **UPDATE** 
Here is the answer...bad formatting!  Payload should be "{"data":{"pull":"true"}}" but I was sending "{"pull":"true"}"  Main thread can be found [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2230081)

Comment: Actually the payload should be `curl -f -X PUT -d 'data={"pull":"true"}' "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps/2519522?access_token=${PHONEGAP_BUILD_ACCESS_TOKEN}"`. Anyway, thanks for this question and linking to your forum post because I made the same mistake and found this helpful to get going myself!

Comment: Hmm, I assume I was just using urlencoded for the request itself instead of JSON or something.